# SwiftUI Button ListRowBackgroundColor doesn't Change

Tags: swift, swiftui, swiftui-list, swiftui-button

I'm attempting to recreate a button that simulates the behavior of a `NavigationLink` inside a `List` in SwiftUI. However, when tapping the button wrapped inside the `List`, the `listRowBackground` color doesn't change, even when long-pressing due to my `Custom ButtonStyle`. When removing the `ButtonStyle`, the `ListRowBackground` stays the same on short tap. However, on long press it now changes the color. I just want the `Button` to change the L`istRowBackgroundColor` on short- and longpress.

Here's a simplified version of my code:

```
List {
    NavigationButton(imageString: "lock.fill", imageColor: .cyan, text: "Data Protection") {
        // Action
    }
}

private struct NavigationButton: View {
    @Environment(\.colorScheme) var colorScheme
    let imageString: String
    let imageColor: Color
    let text: String
    let action: () -> Void

    var body: some View {
        Button {
            action()
        } label: {
            // Button content
        }
        .buttonStyle(NavigationLinkButtonStyle())
    }
}

private struct NavigationLinkButtonStyle: ButtonStyle {
    func makeBody(configuration: Configuration) -> some View {
        configuration.label
            .listRowBackground(configuration.isPressed ? Color.red.opacity(0.3) : Color.red)
    }
}
```

In this code, the default background color of the `ListRowBackground` is set to red for testing purposes. However, the background remains the default SwiftUI `List` color when the button is tapped.

I have also tried setting the `ListRowBackground` directly after the `NavigationButton`:

```swift
List {
    NavigationButton(imageString: "lock.fill", imageColor: .cyan, text: "Data Protection") {
        // Action
    }
    .listRowBackground(Color.red)
}
```

This resulted in the view actually having the `Backgroundcolor`, but now I'd need to pass a `Binding` down to the `ButtonStyle` and change it down there, when `configuration.isPressed` changes to adjust the `ListRowBackground` in the view, which is really suboptimal.

How can I fix this and adjust the background color correctly, as it is in the default `NavigationLink`?